# What risks are there in copying files?

Tags: hard-drive, file-transfer, data-transfer

I'm trying to get a better understanding of what happens when data is copied from one drive to another. When I selected a file a file from my local drive to be copied onto another drive, what happens to ensure that the file has been copied correctly to the second drive?

Are there enough fail-safes in the copy process to ensure that the data I copy is exactly the same as what was on the first drive or am I better doing a CRC check? If the copied data shows as the same size as the source I copied it from, can I assume nothing has gone wrong?

Comment: Checksums or Hashes can help ensure that what you got after it being copied or moved is the same source data or not.

Comment: @Mohi I guess a hash  GUARANTEES that you know whether or not it copied correctly. It doesn't  ensure or help or "help ensure".

Comment: @barlop Apologies for bad use of my vocabulary. :)

Answer (score 0):

Risks? There are always risks in copying data, you are moving hundreds, thousands, millions, billions, or potentially even more bits of 0's and 1's from a source to a destination, there is always a risk a 0 could be misinterpreted as 1 or a bit could get dropped along the way, but as long as things are operating properly, the risks are very low.

Although it depends on the Operating System and application used to perform the copy or data transfer, in general the copy operation is blind... Meaning all it does is read in data from once source, and write it to a destination without any form of checksum or verification by default done by the application itself. In a properly operating, modern computer this should be fine and rarely causes an issues. There are applications for various operating systems that have checksum and verification built in, such as [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy) for Windows, [UltraCopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/) for Mac, or [crccp/crcmv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/crcsum/), or even `rsync`, for Linux.

Of course, you can always do a md5sum comparison after the fact to see if A=B, or utilities such as `diff` or [UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare.html)

And for the size of things being identical from the original to the destination is a very good indication things went properly, but it is not perfect... How much you trust it would depend on how much you value the copy and how dependent you are on it.